# Wordpress admin categories sort show is wrong

Tags: categories, wp-admin

I create categories like:

```
A
-- A1
-- A2
---- A21
---- A22
-- A3
B
-- B1
-- B2
C
```

But in new post on left side admin show wrong:

```
A
-- A1
---- A21
---- A22
B
-- B2
C
A2
A3
B1
```

Why? How I can fix it?

Code:

```
$id = wp_create_category('title', $parent);
```

Image : [image]

Comment: it must be show you correctly as you expected. is this custom taxonomy?

Comment: @Bhautik no, it is category in wordpress. url is : wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category

Comment: maybe something conflict with category. i just checked in my local working fine. see this image https://imgur.com/SorRXNp

Comment: @Bhautik I create categories with wp_create_category() function. in admin category show correct, but in send new post show incorrect.

Comment: can you attach screenshots in question? and also add the code for wp_create_category that you did.

Comment: @Bhautik please check my question again. I added.

Comment: I am not checking if it will be alphabetically here but imho it is much better to use [`wp_insert_term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/). A very nice explanation to read the why, you can read when following this link to [Tom McFarlin](https://tommcfarlin.com/programmatically-create-categories/) his site.